# PHP text variable change color

Tags: html, css

How can I solve that variables in the $var ($a $b and $c) be red and other texts (this is test, is) be normal black.
**Thank you for your answer!**

```
$a = 125;
$b = "My text";
$c = "is";

$var = "This is test $b is $c $a.";
echo '<div class="test">', $var,'</div>';

<style>
.test {
  color: #000000;
  z-index: 8;
  display: block;
  font-weight: normal;
  position:relative;
  left: -1255px;
  top: -345px;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 30px;
  max-width: 1450px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I'm confused - what are you actually asking?

Comment: Suround your variable with tag `<span>` and add color to these

Comment: Wrap them in a `span` tag each with something like a `class="red"` attribute?

Comment: In php, you can use . (dot) to add variables together echo '<div class="test">'. $var.'</div>';

Comment: your `$var` is a string echoed to your page, if you want to add HTML to format things, you can add it directly to your string: `$var = "This is test <span class=\"text-red\">$b</span> ...";` (with adding the CSS style for the text-red class, of course)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap those variables in an element and style those. That element could be just `<span>` if you only want the color, or (which I prefer) a more descriptive element like `<em>` if it would make semantical sense to emphasize those values. Whichever you choose, once you outputted the elements, you can style them as usual:

```
$a = 125;
$b = "My text";
$c = "is";

$var = "This is test <em>$b</em> is <em>$c</em> <em>$a</em>.";
echo '<div class="test">'.$var.'</div>';
```

Note the added `.test em` rule in the style sheet to address all (and only) the `<em>` elements inside your `.test` div.

```
<style>
.test {
  color: #000000;
  z-index: 8;
  display: block;
  font-weight: normal;
  position:relative;
  left: -1255px;
  top: -345px;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 30px;
  max-width: 1450px;
}
.test em {
  color: red;
}
</style>
```

See [`<em>`: The Emphasis element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/em) on Mozilla for more information about this element in particular and the general difference between (just) visual and semantic markup.

Answer (score -1):

```
$a = 125;
$b = "My text";
$c = "is";

$var = "This is test $b is $c $a.";
echo '<div class="test">', $var,'</div>';

echo '<style>
.test {
  color: #000000;
  z-index: 8;
  display: block;
  font-weight: normal;
  position:relative;
  left: -1255px;
  top: -345px;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 30px;
  max-width: 1450px;
}
</style>';
```